# Magento 1.9 SOAP product update - out of stock

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, bug

I manage to update products by SOAP api, but after update my products have 'Out of stock' label. It looks like Magento bug, because I am not updating stock inventory and I don't use this feature in my shop.
I found that after update when I go to backend and open and resave product 'out of stock" disappears. I empty cache and reidnex everything, still no success.
Please help how to fix it ? 
I am using 'catalog_product.update'

Answer (score 0):

OK. Solved. System > Configuration > Catalog -> Frontent > Flat Catalog Product 
disable it ! It makes problems !